# C++ Visual Studio: retrieve my debug property sheet

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How can I set my release mode properties to be same as my debug properties? Knowing that I don't the debug property sheet. Is there a way to retrieve it (instead of copying line by line), to add it to my release mode? And if not, is there a way to build on release mode with same properties as debug without passing by the property sheets?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the same project properties for both Debug & Release without copying them line by line, the solution is to use property sheets.

Use menu **View->Other Windows->Property Manager**
Expand your project to see the Debug & Release configurations.

Right click on Debug and choose "**Add New Project Property Sheet**..." to create one.

After filling its properties, you can right click on Release and choose "**Add Existing Property Sheet**" and select the one you just created so that both configurations share the same property sheet.

If you already have a property sheet in your project, its name should appear in the Property Manager when you expand the Debug or Release node.
If you want to find the file path for this property sheet, select its name and press ALT+RETURN. The Properties pane should show the full pathname.

if you have already have one you want to use also in this configuration.